# Обмен данными по com порту

Tags: linux, c, передача-данных

В учебных целях хочу передавать и считывать данные на `com`-порт.

Есть фискальный регистратор, который принимает пакетные сообщения по ком порту. В официальной документации касательно передачи данных описано не много:

> Тип протокола - Master (ПК) / Slave (фискальный регистратор).
> Фискальный регистратор выполняет команды, переданные ему от ПК, и возвращает сообщение, зависящие от результата выполнения. Фискальный регистратор не может инициировать сеанс связи с ПК. Сообщения в протоколе - это пакеты или одиночные байты.
> Фискальный регистратор поддерживает связь по интерфейсу RS 232 со скоростью 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400,
> 57600 и 115200 bps, 8N1.

В поисках ответов на свои вопросы, я понял что это протокол `modbus`.Путем декомпиляции софта производителя написанного на `c#` прояснилось много деталей. Свою реализацию пишу на `с++`, поэтому сделал функцию формирования массива байт, который содержит в себе команду для регистратора, пытаюсь его отправить на `com`-порт.

Вот мой код:

```
void init_tty(int fd)
{
    struct termios ter;
    tcgetattr(fd, &ter);
    ter.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; 
    ter.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    ter.c_cflag |= CS8;
    ter.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    ter.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    ter.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    ter.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     
    ter.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;
    cfsetispeed(&ter, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&ter, B115200);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &ter);

}
int main() {
int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR);
init_tty(fd);
int len;
ushort *arr = CommandFormation(122,"N,",len);
int nw;
    nw = write(fd, arr, len);
    if ( nw <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << " from write" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Отправлено байт " << nw << endl;
```

Порт открывается корректно, функция `write()` возвращает именно столько, сколько я и отправлял. Однако устройство не выполняет команду.

Некорректность пакетного сообщения вероятнее всего исключается, так как метод в коде производителя возвращает точно такой же массив байт, как и моя реализация. Что я делаю не правильно, возможно я не корректно настраиваю структуру `termios`?

Comment: Вы не проверяли с помощью AccessPort или подобного перехватчика, с одинаковыми ли параметрами открывают порт штатная программа и ваша, а также побайтно сравнить посылку от обеих программ?

Comment: А читаете вы как? Также смущает `int len; ushort *arr = CommandFormation(122,"N,",len);`, т.к. len не инициализирована. Я бы еще добавил `c_cc[VMIN] = 1; c_cc[VTIME] = 0;`  и `c_lfalg &= ~(ECHOK | ECHOKE | ECHONL | ECHOCTL | IEXTEN);`. Ну, и попробовать с разными скоростями не мешает

Comment: Можно еще CSTOPB явно сбросить (если в `8N1` 1 означает один стоп-бит)

Comment: И все же, распечатайте `len` перед write, покажите, как вы читаете устройство и попробуйте с разными скоростями. Также можно вызвать (через system) `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` до и после вызова `init_tty(fd);` и вставить результат обеих вызовов в текст вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена просто, благодаря подсказке [@mbo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo). Действительно, по скольку я работаю в *Linux* мне было немного проще реализовать "перехват" того что посылает ПО производителя. В параметрах порта я указал свой псевдо-терминал и отправил на него команду. Таким образом, получив пакет данных от ПО производителя, я смог разобраться почему мой код не работал. Фискальный регистратор не выполняет команды если ее порядковый номер повторяется с предыдущей.